# Why is CSS mask-image not working with no-repeat?

Tags: html, css, image, image-masking

I have a SVG and I'd like to change its color to red on some event, but you can't do that with SVG as a background-image, so you have to use CSS `image-mask`. I'm using PHP to echo my CSS onto the style attribute of the div:

```
$jfid = "background-color:red;
        -webkit-mask-image:url(../like_icons/" . $iconfgg . ".svg);
         mask-image:url(../like_icons/" . $iconfgg . ".svg)";
```

Like

```css
.buttonlikee {
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transition: 0.8s all ease
}
.ts{
  width: 34px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color:red;
  -webkit-mask-image:url(https://svgshare.com/i/CB7.svg);
  mask-image:url(https://svgshare.com/i/CB7.svg) 
}
```

```html
<button class="buttonlikee">
  <div class="ts"></div>
</button>
```

This works as expected but returns a repeated image of the same SVG. So the solution would be to add `no-repeat` at last like this:

```
$jfid = "background-color:red;
         -webkit-mask-image:url(../like_icons/" . $iconfgg . ".svg) no-repeat;
         mask-image:url(../like_icons/" . $iconfgg . ".svg) no-repeat";
```

This in return gives me a div full of red color and  you can't see the icon like

```css
.buttonlikee {
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transition: 0.8s all ease
}
.ts{
  width: 34px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color:red;
  -webkit-mask-image:url(https://svgshare.com/i/CB7.svg) no-repeat;
  mask-image:url(https://svgshare.com/i/CB7.svg) no-repeat
}
```

```html
<button class="buttonlikee">
  <div class="ts"></div>
</button>
```

Is this a bug? What could be the solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`no-repeat` is not a valid command for the `mask-image` property as seen in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image). Instead you should use the [`mask-repeat` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-repeat) like so:

```css
.buttonlikee {
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transition: 0.8s all ease
}
.ts {
  width: 34px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color:red;
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/CB7.svg);
  mask-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/CB7.svg);
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<button class="buttonlikee">
  <div class="ts"></div>
</button>
```

Otherwise you can use the [`mask` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) shorthand:

```css
.buttonlikee {
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transition: 0.8s all ease
}
.ts {
  width: 34px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color:red;
  -webkit-mask: url(https://svgshare.com/i/CB7.svg) no-repeat;
  mask: url(https://svgshare.com/i/CB7.svg) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<button class="buttonlikee">
  <div class="ts"></div>
</button>
```